# Google cloud functions: functions.https.onCall returning null but the value is shown correctly in the logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a third-party API via Axios async-await, and returning the result to a flutter application via a google cloud function. I am forced to use `functions.https.onCall` because flutter can't call `onRequest` functions as far as I know.

The result is shown correctly in `console.log` in the logs of the cloud function but when the flutter app calls the function, it's always receiving `null`. Why?

```
getSmsBalance: functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const business_id = data.business_id;
    const collectionRef = db.collection("buser_sms");
    const snapshot = await collectionRef.where("id", "==", business_id).get();
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents - getSMSBalance .");
        let response = {
            status: false,
        };
        return JSON.stringify(response);
    }
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (
            doc.data().enableReservationSms == true ||
            doc.data().enableAutoReminder == true ||
            doc.data().enableReminderSms == true
        ) {
            // get balance
            (async () => {
                const balance = await getBalance(
                    doc.data().senderId,
                    doc.data().username,
                    doc.data().password
                )
                    .then((result) => {
                        let response = {
                            status: true,
                            data: result,
                        };
                        console.log("balance is " + result);
                        return JSON.stringify(response);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error(`Error - getSmsBalance - ${err}`);
                        let response = {
                            status: false,
                        };
                        return JSON.stringify(response);
                    });
            })();
        }
    });
}),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are using async/await syntax inside an `Array.forEach` which does not allow to await because of its intrinsic design. If you want to use async/await within the loop iterations, you need to use `Array.map` for example. But in most cases, you shouldn't use async/await inside a loop because it removes the advantages of asynchronous code execution (each iteration is only triggered after the previous one).
2. You don't return anything from your function, except in the case of `snapshot.empty`. The `return`s in the `then` and `catch` callbacks only assign the values to the variable `balance` which isn't used afterwards.

So in conclusion, you need to use something like:

```
  return Promise.all(
    snapshot.map((doc) => {
      return getBalance(
        doc.data().senderId,
        doc.data().username,
        doc.data().password
      )
        .then((result) => {
          let response = {
            status: true,
            data: result,
          };
          console.log('balance is ' + result);
          return JSON.stringify(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(`Error - getSmsBalance - ${err}`);
          let response = {
            status: false,
          };
          return JSON.stringify(response);
        });
    })
  );
```

Note that I'm providing that code snipped without any consideration for what format you actually need as the output. Having an array of `response`s may not be what you need. But you should be able to adapt that code to what you need in the end.

Comment: You're welcome, but why did you replace the fat arrow function by a traditional function in my answer ?

Comment: by mistake, what I really wanted to replace is `snapshot.docs.map`. Fixed now.

Comment: Indeed, force of habit with loops and names ^^. I fixed the code snippet :)